# SAS find unique couples in dataset

Tags: sas

I'm working with a SAS dataset and I'm wondering on how to solve this problem is SAS.

I'm trying to find unique rides for a taxi-driver, 
where A to B and B to A count as one unique ride.

Small example to illustrate:

The dataset:

```
Taxidriver_ID From      To        date
------------------------------------------
0123          Address_1 Address_2 1jan2017                  
0123          Address_2 Address_1 1jan2017
0123          Address_3 Address_1 5jan2017
0123          Address_1 Address_3 5jan2017
0123          Address_1 Address_3 6jan2017
0123          Address_4 Address_5 1jan2017
```

I would like to classify this as 3 unique rides for taxidriver 0123:
1 to 2 (and reverse),
1 to 3 (and reverse) and
4 to 5

and I would like to count the amount of these unique rides.
In the example that is 4 rides 
(1 to 2) once
(1 to 3) twice
(4 to 5) once

Help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Please demonstrate that you've attempted to solve this problem yourself. What have you tried? Why didn't it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first question can be solved with a `select distinct` in combination min/max comparisons on the addresses.

```
data have;
infile datalines;
input taxidriver_id $ from $ to $ date :anydtdte.;
format date date.;
datalines;
0123 Addr_1 Addr_2 1jan2017                  
0123 Addr_2 Addr_1 1jan2017
0123 Addr_3 Addr_1 5jan2017
0123 Addr_1 Addr_3 5jan2017
0123 Addr_1 Addr_3 6jan2017
0123 Addr_4 Addr_5 1jan2017
;
run;

proc sql;
create table want as
select distinct taxidriver_id
               ,ifc(from<to,from,to) as from
               ,ifc(from>to,from,to) as to
from have
;
quit;
```

Your second question can be answered by building on that:

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select taxidriver_id
      ,from
      ,to
      ,count(*) as count
from (
    select distinct taxidriver_id
                   ,ifc(from<to,from,to) as from
                   ,ifc(from>to,from,to) as to
                   ,date
    from have
)
group by taxidriver_id, from, to
;
quit;
```